# Unable to access ID property from a datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore

Using Google App Engine SDK and Python, I'm facing an issue : I'm unable to access the ID property of a given entity properties. The only properties I can access are those defined in my class Model, plus the key property (see answer below) :

```
class Question(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty()
    answers = db.StringListProperty()
    user = db.UserProperty()
    datetime = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

I can access text, answers, user, datetime and key properties just fine. However, I can't access the ID property.
For example, after fetching all entities (using Question.all()) :

```
# OK Within a template, this will return a string :
{{ question.text }}
# OK, this will return the entity key :
{{ question.key }}

# KO this will return nothing :
{{ question.id }}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: key and id aren't properties of a datastore entity.  key() is an instance method, and id() is an instance method of the Key.  {{entity.key.id}} only works because the bit after the . will be interpreted as a method call when appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the **[documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html)**, there is no `id()` instance method defined for Model subclasses.

Try `{{ question.key }}` instead.

Also note that the key is not created until the entity is saved to the datastore.

---

Edit:  more info based on OP's edit:

Since we're really after the **numeric ID**, we could do something like this in our template:

`{{ question.key.id }}`

Another note:  you should never expect numeric IDs to increase in value corresponding with the order of entity creation.  In practice, this is usually—but not always—the case.

Comment: Indeed, {{ question.key }} works fine and returns the key stored in the Datastore. I should have double-checked ! I might edit my original post. So I guess retrieving the ID is the only issue left.

Comment: @Sorw:  Anytime.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: @bernie, this is exactly what i was looking for and I spent nearly tow hours searching.

Comment: glad that you found this, then. happy coding

Answer (score 5):

I just found a possible (inelegant, IMO) solution. After querying and fetching entities, loop through all of them and manually add the id parameter :

```
query = Question.all()
questions = query.fetch(10)

# Add ID property :
for question in questions:
    question.id = str(question.key().id())
```

I don't think it's efficient CPU wise, but it works as a quick/dirty fix.

Comment: @Adam: hehe I think we both found a possible solution at the same time, but yours is a lot simplier !

Comment: Inelegant, perhaps, but +1 to you for arriving at a solution.