# Access the numeric ID for an entity in google app engine's datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I've taken a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218693/unable-to-access-id-property-from-a-datastore-entity), on accessing id from datastore. Now I tried doing something like `post.key().id()` but it does not return the Numeric ID that I want.

How does one access the numeric ID of an entity in google datastore. I am using GAE 1.8 wiht Python 2.7. I believe a lot has changed from the time of the question that I just showed you.

This is all an attempt to make a permalink for my entity called `post`, which is a blog post.

Here is the code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from google.appengine.ext import db


class BlogPost(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created_at = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    def url(self):
        return '/blog/%s' % self.key().id()
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it return? Nothing of significance has changed since the question you linked to.

Comment: @Greg: First thanks for replying. It returns the entire object. `<Objec ~~~ at memory address 0x987938475>` <- something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting this is the method to get the numeric id.

If you get None then it means you have created the entity using a string for the id.

You could try

`key().id_or_name()`
Returns the name or numeric ID of the data entity, whichever it has, or None if the entity has neither a name nor a numeric ID.

If you get None from `id_or_name()` it means the entity has yet to be `put()`

Comment: This works in the template, but when I do `self.key().id_or_name()`, it gives me something like this : `<bound method BlogPost.url of <models.BlogPost object at 0x03F716B0>>`

Comment: Look at what you are getting.  You have the object but you code is trying to access 'url' method of a blogpost object, but not calling the method.  So I would assume id() also works, your just never calling url method.

Comment: Sorry to sound really dumb, but what do I have to do then? I'm kinda confused. A code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well how are you using BlogPost.url.  I can't see the template. You don't provide an example of how the page is rendered.

Comment: Arrite got it worked out. I just had to do, `db.key.from_path('BlogPost' int(key))` to get the key, and then just `db.get(key)`

Answer (score 0):

When you create an entity, you specify an ancestor key, and one of either a string name, or a numeric id.

If you create it with a string, there is no numeric id.

You probably want name(), or if you're not sure id_or_name()

Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id_or_name